# Align text vertically inside div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML & CSS code.

I'd like to position all my text vertically centered. Even 'Text here' would be left aligned to the logo. Can someone explain how I achieve this with my code? Many thanks.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z6yet59f/

```css
.slogan {
    background:#eaeaea;
    float:left;
    width:600px
}

.slogan img {
    cursor: pointer;
    width:92px;
    height:92px
}

.slogan div {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.slogan div span {
    display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="slogan">
    <div>
            <p>
                <span>Text here</span>
                <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-social/32/blog_blogger_google-128.png" id="chat_link_35" title="click to start live chat ..">
            </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="heading">National Helpline</span>
        <span>Hello</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="heading" style="color:orange">National Helpline</span>
        <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically Align text in a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: This [MDN article on vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is probably a better resource than the one at that answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please find the updated code below, hope it will resolve your issue.**

```css
.slogan {
    background:#eaeaea;
    float:left;
    width:600px
}

.slogan img {
    cursor: pointer;
    width:92px;
    height:92px;
     vertical-align: middle;
}

.slogan div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: 35px;
}
.slogan div p{display:block;}
   .slogan div p span{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.slogan div span {
    display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="slogan">
    <div>
            <p>
                <span>Text here</span>
                <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-social/32/blog_blogger_google-128.png" id="chat_link_35" title="click to start live chat ..">
            </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="heading">National Helpline</span>
        <span>Hello</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="heading" style="color:orange">National Helpline</span>
        <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. It's 99% perfect. How do I move the `Text here` to be left of the logo?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk - Just put `Text here` in a `div` before the one containing the image instead of in a paragraph with the image.

Comment: Please find the updated code, it will work and resolve the other issue as well. let me know any further issue :) @michaelmcgurk

Comment: @CreativePS You are a star! A star! :-D

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: Thanks, if the answer solve your issues completely, it would be great if you can mark the answer as best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this class `.valign-middle`

**CSS**

```
.valign-middle {
    -webkit-display: flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slogan valign-middle">
    <div>
        <p> <span>Text here</span>

            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-social/32/blog_blogger_google-128.png" id="chat_link_35" title="click to start live chat ..">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div> <span class="heading">National Helpline</span>
 <span>Hello</span>

    </div>
    <div> <span class="heading" style="color:orange">National Helpline</span>
 <span>Hello</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/3/)**

Comment: Is there a way to do this which will work in some of the older IE browsers?